# Is it possible to use the same version for multiple dependencies in a csproj file?

Tags: c#, csproj

I have a C# project (.NET6) that looks like this:

project.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.0" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Is it somehow possible to maintain these dependency-versions in one place (they all belong together)?
Similar to what e.g. [Maven allows by using a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358318/maven-dependency-version-as-property)?

The problem is that when I want to update - e.g. to `6.0.1` - I always have to update all dependency-versions at once. Which is in particularly a problem when using automatic tools like [Dependabot](https://github.com/dependabot) as they usually create one pull request for each dependency because they are unable to recognize that these dependencies belong together.

I also checked but I didn't find any other solutions so far, neither on StackOverflow nor in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that works. Just use a variable for the versions.

Like so:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EntityFrameworkVersion>6.0.0</EntityFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="$(EntityFrameworkVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="$(EntityFrameworkVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="$(EntityFrameworkVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="$(EntityFrameworkVersion)" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now you only have to edit a single line to update the version. I normally even move the variable definition to the top-level `Directory.build.props` file, so that I only need to edit one single line to update the version across all projects in the solution.

There are two possible problems with this solution:

- I'm not sure (and never really tested) whether dependabot is able to resolve this. It might not be.
- From experience, when the solution is large (many projects that have this dependency) updating the `Directory.build.props` file often crashes Visual Studio. When closing it before changing the version, everything is fine, though.

Comment: `I normally even move the variable definition to the top-level Directory.build.props file` I wouldn't do this - it means *every* project in your solution will have the same versions _directly installed_. I would much prefer the correct versions to be installed through nuget working out the transitive dependencies...

Comment: @RB. Maybe "normally" was not the correct word. "sometimes" would have been better. I particularly use this for a dependency that is referenced (directly) from many projects within the solution and for which I really only want to have one version in use.

Comment: You'd only need to do that if the projects did not reference each other though - which would be an unusual scenario, but in that case I would use this approach. Otherwise I think keeping the dependencies in the project file is much less surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can simplify your references because the other 2 [are](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) [dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/) and will be automatically included.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you did want them to share the version, you can define a property for the version:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EfVersion>6.0.0</EfVersion>
<PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="$(EfVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="$(EfVersion)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this - as soon as you use any tooling (like the Nuget Package Manager) to update these references, you will likely run into problems (from memory it will replace the `EfVersion` with the concrete version, but that will be a tool-specific implementation detail).